# How do I get the output from one page printed to another page (cross domain)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a small script with ASP.NET that outputs all sorts of javascript codes. (`document.write('aaa');`)

To call this outputs, I am using a simple  tag on any domain I want it to show, and it works.
In one website, I need to refresh the string printed to the page every X seconds.

What can I do to accomplish this without changing the basic  tag?

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand, you have

1. an asp.net page that outputs javascript code. This codes writes a string.
2. web pages with a  tag that loads this page and executes the javascript

and you want to know how you could refresh the string every X seconds.

Here is the start of a solution :

1. add a setTimeout call to a function every X seconds
2. make sure this function clears the zone where the string was written
3. make sure this function reload the asp.net page either by updating the script.src or appending a new script tag on the page

I hope this will help you

Comment: do you mean that if I will add a function that loops every X seconds in my JS file it will update in the other page where the <script> tag is used?

Comment: more or less, yes. If you instruct the browser, via the script loaded in the <script> tag, to do something in X seconds, the browser will do it.